# Display image in RSFORM after passing it through URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, rsform

So far i have been able to pass a K2 image into both a textbox and a hidden field of RSFORM - which is great! But i would like the user to view the item (image) they are ordering while filling the form.

I came across this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485539/use-image-url-in-text-box-to-display-pic-after-submit) with this solution:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1" />
</form>
<div id="photo"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';
});
</script>
```

The solution above is slightly similar to what i want only that i want my image to be viewed before submission and to be submitted as well.

**My Thoughts:**
I think using the rsform **hidden field** to catch the image and then passing it to an `<img src="" />` tag using java-script for it to be displayed may work as in the example above.

Please, i need your kind assistance in solving this and if you need more clarifications to the problem, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer

**This worked perfectly:**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ document.getElementById('fieldname').value +'" alt="Image" />';
});
</script>
```

Enter this in the **script section** of your form and disable the **auto layout generation** in rsform and place this `<div id="photo"></div>` where you want your image to appear in the form then replace **fieldname** in the code with the name of your field.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with PHP using the "Scripts called on form display" section.  The basic steps would be:

1. Set variable to the image path you are passing (ie $_GET, etc)
2. Set variable to the placeholder image value
3. Do a find/replace using the syntax below:

   $formLayout = str_replace($find,$replace,$formLayout);